# Switching between two windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose i have two different windows in WPF application Window1 and Window2.

Based on some actions from Window1, Window2 pop up for a while, and also based on some actions in Window1, Window2 should close and view returns to Window1 with it's state before Window2 appears.

With it's state i mean with all the content in all the controls that exists in Window1.

To achieve the switching i used

> ShowDialog();

which i was looking exactly because i need Window1 to freeze while Window2 is on.

Right now my problem i can't return to Window1 with it's content.

> MainWindow (Window1).xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="193,130,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

> Button_Click

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 window1 = new Window1();
    window1.ShowDialog();

    //Actions

    window1.Close();
}
```

and the Window1 xaml is a normal one i didn't change anything except that i made the

> WindowStyle=None

so i can't exit it with the right top exit button

Comment: Just close the Window2 "based on some actions" as you've worded it.

Comment: @AlexBell Thanks for your reply , not our first time to meet :) .. how can i achieve this the Close() doesn't make anything

Comment: There should be a "Close" Button in the Window's Upper-Right control box; also you can call the window.Close(); method from the event handler associated with some Control's in that Windows2. In order to get more detailed answer please include the entire code snippet related to the issue. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell thanks for your reply again, see my edits please

Comment: So, what is Window1 and Window2 ? Your code snippets seems completely wrong. Please clarify.

Comment: @AlexBell sorry for this confusing naming. Window1 here is the MainWindow and the other window which i call in the button click event is Window2

Comment: The code and the business logic are both very confusing: what are you trying to accomplish with that second (Dialog) window? And what kind of those  "// Actions" you put into that code? Please be very accurate/specific as this discussion is getting too lengthy. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MVVM you can use this:

```
public static class DialogCloser
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogResultProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DialogResult",
            typeof(bool?),
            typeof(DialogCloser),
            new PropertyMetadata(DialogResultChanged));

    private static void DialogResultChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = d as Window;
        if (window != null)
            window.DialogResult = e.NewValue as bool?;
    }
    public static void SetDialogResult(Window target, bool? value)
    {
        target.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/
    xmlns:xc="clr-namespace:Window2"
    xc:DialogCloser.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}"
```

Then in Model you can use:

```
 public bool? DialogResult
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: I figured at last that using MVVM the the solution for many problems, Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 3):

This topic is too old but perhaps this is what you were talking about?

```
// Currently in Window1, want to open window2 and make window1 not visible
private void Change_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 mainWindow = new Window2();
            Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Window2.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question and business logic is a bit unclear, so the answer is based on a qualified guess: in order to open the second WPF Window (window2) in a Dialog Mode, use the following generic code:

```
Window2 _window2 = new Window2()
{
    Title = "Modal Dialog Window",
    Topmost = true,
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
    ShowInTaskbar = false,
    Owner = this
};
_window2.ShowDialog();
```

In order to close that second `window2` , use either the standard "Close" Button in the Upper-Right Control Box, or add the `Button` to that `window2` and put `this.Close()` statement into that Button `Click` event.

*Edited per your additional comments*: If you show the second window as a Modal Dialog then you are blocking the Owner Window (like popping the MessageBox, for example). Please clarify your business logic because it's very unclear why you need to open the second window and then close it from the main one. What kind of "Actions" you put between Opening and Closing that second window in the Button Click event of main window? You may consider opening a second window in normal mode, then you can close it from main Window using for example, some Button control placed on the first window. It seems you have to refine the business logic.

Hope this may help.

Comment: I've extended the answer with detailed explanation: it seems that you have to refine your business logic first, and then implement the code base as described in my answer. At this point I am closing this discussion. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Here's what commonly worked for me:

```
Dim TheAboutWindow As New winAbout
TheAboutWindow.Owner = Me
TheAboutWindow.ShowDialog()
TheAboutWindow = Nothing
```

Sometimes I use My.Windows.winName when I don't want to load stuff over and over again, but you need to cancel the close and hide the window somehow.

But there is one thing that is great about My.Windows.winName, you don't need to remember the variable name and it's usually accessible for any open window. (Not sure how that works when two instances are open though.)

That means you can do My.Windows.winMain.Title = "OMG Jawj. Did you see that?"

```
My.Windows.winHost.Owner = Me
My.Windows.winHost.ShowDialog()
```

You can/should omit the owner line if you want to perform minimizing features from the child and show the child again on max/normal.